# Different GET and POST cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, session-cookies

In node.js, I created a server and tried to print headers.cookie. But one thing I've noticed is that when I perform a GET method, the `request.header.cookie` give the result that I expected but when I perform POST method using AJAX, `request.headers.cookie` returns empty. Is cookies created using GET differs from cookies created using POST?

Comment: The cookies should be the same.

Comment: but when I reload the page, it gives ```request.headers.cookie``` undefined, while it gives me the cookie that I've set when using AJAX POST?

Comment: I'm not sure about how you read the cookie from Node, but you can use the browser "Network" developer tool to verify that the cookie header is the same.

Comment: I tried document.cookie in the console, the result is "" but the cookie appears in node when using "POST"

Comment: Is it a cross-domain ajax request?

Comment: nope, actually, the cookies were created during ajax function and only appears during ajax(POST) method.